# use RegExp with test using javascript getAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm setting a regular expression on a jsx element and then on input change I want to get the regular expression and test the input's value but I am getting the error as RegExp is not a constructor.
This is the input:

```
<input type="text" regex=/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/ onChange = { this.onInputChange } />
```

and this is the event set on it:

```
onInputChange(e) {
    const regex = new RegExp(e.target.getAttribute('regex'))
    console.log(regex.test(e.target.value)
}
```

while typing numbers which should evaluate to true I get the error 
***TypeError: core_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.RegExp is not a constructor***

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would expect that your attribute should be quoted `regex="^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$"` and better yet, you should be using a data attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have an incorrect import like this:

```js
import RegExp from '...';
```

You need to remove the import completely.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to below.

`<input type="text" regex=/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/ onChange = {(e)=> this.onInputChange(e) } />`